# What to choose EF with stored procedure OR EF with T-SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, data-access-layer

I want to know view and approach what is best to choose with for new project.

My New project will have - Two databases where, mutual relationship for related tables between two databases.

also, stored procedure logic can be more then simple CRUD operation.

Application will be in MVC 4. I afraid, EF may not be take more cost to develop. I am new to EF as well, usvally go with ADO.NET with stored procedure.

Kindly, suggest,
1. I will require to use stored procedure as the major benefit is no need to recompile the .NET code in case any change of procedure, and maintain separately at database side so, could be change directly if require.
Though, any benefit to use as T-SQL statement (no stored procedure) with EF on front-end side ?
2. Entity Framework with stored procedure is good design or it may cost more then ADO.NET ?

Please guide to decide this ?

Thank You

Comment: I think you should choose both, you can take advantage of all the objects created by the EF. 

Use store procedure(ADO.NET not the functions stuff of EF, that's annoying you have to import every procedure into the Model) to perform Read/write/delete ..  operation

Comment: Can you share any link or documentation for such architacture using EF with stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you can use your stored procedures in EF as well so you get the best of both worlds so i would definitely go with EF.

Comment: Is there any cost of performance as it will not use already generated code (sql statements) and EF (datacontext) will just use to call stored procedure. what is best ADO.NET in this scenario or ef.